# Linq - OrderByDescending and Take(1), will it return max item?

Tags: c#, linq

*I have this line of C# code:*

```
datavals
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.ElementID, x.OutputTableCode})
  .SelectMany(x => x
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.Sequence)
     .Take(1))
  .ToList<TransactionValue<string>>();
```

The idea is to group the items in the list by the `ElementID` and the `OutputTableCode`, then to order each group according to the descending Sequence, and to return only one item per group. (This is actually in a return statement, so the modified list will be returned to the calling function.)

My question is, will this return the item with the maximum Sequence, or is that not necessarily the case? In my test example, it does, but not sure whether it is guaranteed.

If it won't necessarily return the item with the maximum Sequence in each group, how can I change the query to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify Just use `OrderBy` and get last item with `LastOrDefault`. also instead of `SelectMany` you have to use `Select`

```
   datavals.GroupBy(x => new { x.ElementID, x.OutputTableCode})
           .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Sequence)
           .LastOrDefault()).ToList<TransactionValue<string>>();
```

> My question is, will this return the item with the maximum Sequence, or is that not necessarily the case? In my test example, it does, but not sure whether it is guaranteed.

Yes. it will always return the item with maximum sequence. Since its ordered and you are taking the last item there is no way that the last item does not have maximum `Sequence`.

Instead use this query as its more readable and understandable.

Here is what you have done. Imagine this array. `{5,3,0,4,1,2,6}`

After you order this by descending you will get `{6,5,4,3,2,1,0}`. by taking only 1 item from first you will get array of `{6}`. Because its ordered you are always taking the largest value.

Here is what i have done. I just simplified it a bit.

After i order this by ascending i will get `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}`. since this is ordered always the last item have biggest value. simply ill get the last item `6`.

Because `Take()` returns a sequence you have to use `SelectMany` to unwrap it to single item. But `LastOrDefault` returns a single item so you have to use `Select` to directly select the item.

As @Ivan Stoev suggested you can also safely use `Last`. Read his comment below

Comment: `.OrderBy().LastOrDefault()` is equal to `.OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()` which is equal to `.OrderByDescending().Take(1)`

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov yes. i simplified as i said. so OP can better understand whats going on. and the answer is yes.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Not really. `Take` returns a sequence while the other mentioned methods return element.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes thats why i changed SelectMany to Select.

Comment: M.kazem, I know, that was for Mikhail:-) But from the answer it's not clear that this is the key point. Also, after `GroupBy`, the sequence associated with the key cannot be empty, so you can simply use `First` or `Last`.

Comment: Interesting explanation with arrays, but with sequences in general using first is much better than using last. So, `OrderByDescending` + `First` is the right way.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks for the clarification regarding Take(x) returning a sequence. Also, I just prefer using First over Last.

Answer (score 1):

It will always return maximum of sequence or empty sequence if sequence is empty.

We could not know in what order is sequence now, so if we order by desc - we will get sequence, which is ordered by desc (max value - first, min value - last). Performing `.Take(1)` is equal to perform `.FirstOrDefault()`, so we will get the maximum value of sequence.

If you doubt in `.Take()` you can always use `.FirstOrDefault()` or simply `.First()` to retrieve first value of sequence.

If you only want to get max value, you can use linq `.Max()`, where you can set comparer property, for example `.Max(x => x.Sequence)`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Yes, your code will return the item with the maximum Sequence in each group.*

---

Here is an explanation to give you a better understanding of your code:

- **GroupBy** will simply group the items. Grouping will be on `{ x.ElementID, x.OutputTableCode}` combination.
- Then, **SelectMany** call will:

  - first, sort each group in decreasing order of `Sequence`
  - then, `Take()` the *x* with highest `Sequence` value in each group
- Finally, **ToList** will just give you the selected *x*'s of each group as a `List<TransactionValue<string>>`.